# Henceforth, heretofore and notwithstanding thenceforward wherewithal

Tags: terminology

I ***love*** * these kind of words:

> Moreover, therefore, heretofore, hereto, however, notwithstanding,
>   furthermore, henceforth, wherefore, nonetheless, nevertheless,
>   although, withal, howbeit, albeit, thenceforward, suchlike, so on and so
>   forth...

Many are conjunctions but then there examples like:

> Wherewithal, withstand, hereafter...

They are mostly composed of smaller words joined with each other, but personally, I don't think `'breakfast'` or `'cupboard'`, for instance, have the same *quality*.

**What, if any, is the term for this kind of word?**

<sub>* used sparingly, they're really useful to communicate complex ideas efficiently, but overuse makes you sound a bit <del>like a twat</del> ***magisterial***, or potentially betray a lack self-esteem (or at least awareness)  ...</sub>

---

P.S. please feel free to edit and help with [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) on this one.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57768/what-is-the-category-name-for-words-like-notwithstanding-forthwith-etc

Comment: Perhaps you're ready for an exciting career in chartered accountancy.

Comment: @deadrat, even better: *consultancy*

Comment: @Silenus, thanks - that's the one!  Pity that didn't turn up as a suggestion on the right hand side when I was writing it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azkFz1ZbXyU

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603965/2085).

Comment: They're mostly chunks of phrases that become fixed together like tinkertoy assemblies  left out in the rain to harden. They fit into the little places where they came from (if you can find them), and some have been repurposed to fit elsewhere (sort of).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A specific term for a subset of these words is a Pronominal Adverb. Examples include: Hereby, wherefor, whereof, thereof, whereon, herewith, etc. You're actually listing several types of words, but these are the ones I hope you will find most interesting. They fell out of favour in English, but are very common (necessary even) in other germanic languages, and you will still find them all over legal documents.

"I know a bank *whereon* the wild thyme blows" — William Shakespeare

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Univerbation), "**univerbation** is the diachronic process of combining a fixed expression of several words into a new single word."

Comment: And could you please add information describing whether grammarians distinguish between _univerbation_ and _compounding_, and what the discriminators are stated to be if this is the case ... and of course whether all grammarians are agreed on this analysis. _Are 'sleepover' and 'moreover' in different 'fusion classes'?_

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't think that is a necessary component to my answer, but it sounds as though you have different information than I do and perhaps would like to add an answer of your own, and I for one am looking forward to reading it! I'm particularly interested in the inclusion of *anything* that "all grammarians are agreed on"

Comment: _Compounds_ are _any_ words formed by the fusion of (usually two) smaller words, such as _inkwell/ink-well/ink well_ (the third variant here being the 'open compound'). But OP attempts to specify a subset of these.  Wikipedia's definition doesn't exclude say 'inkwell', or _any_ compound word. Is there a more relevant _specifying definition_ (and is Wikipedia inaccurate here)?